# $\log_j(\log_j(\log_j(x)))=\log(x);\ \ j=?$

Tags: transcendental-equations

$\log_j(\log_j(x))=\log(x)$ has solution $j=x^{\exp-W(\log^2(x))}$ for real $x\neq0$, where $W=$ Lambert W function.

But what is the solution to $\log_j(\log_j(\log_j(x)))=\log(x)$? *Mathematica* can't do it - can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the only possible solutions corresponds to $j=\frac 1k$ to make the equation
$$\frac{\log \left(-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{\log (x)}{\log (k)}\right)}{\log
   (k)}\right)}{\log (k)}+\log (x)=0$$ Numerically solving for $x$ for a given $k$, the following (not very exciting) results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & x_k \\
 2 & 0.743810 \\
 3 & 0.773972 \\
 4 & 0.806977 \\
 5 & 0.831510 \\
 6 & 0.849777 \\
 7 & 0.863823 \\
 8 & 0.874964 \\
 9 & 0.884035 \\
 10 & 0.891583 \\
 20 & 0.930106 \\
 30 & 0.945785 \\
 40 & 0.954705 \\
 50 & 0.960604 \\
 60 & 0.964859 \\
 70 & 0.968106 \\
 80 & 0.970684 \\
 90 & 0.972792 \\
 100 & 0.974555 \\
1000 & 0.994683
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

We can make things easier on ourselves defining $a = \ln j$ and $y = \ln x$. First let's look at the two-log case:
$$
\log_j(\log_j(x)) = \frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\frac{y}{a}\right) = \frac{\ln y - \ln a}{a} = y\Longrightarrow ay +\ln(ay) = 2\ln y
$$
The key here is that we have found two one-variable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(h(a,y)) = g(y)$ for some function $h$. $a$ is now isolated, and can be solved as $a = h^{-1}_a(f^{-1}(g(y)),y)$. Ideally we can choose $f$ and $g$ such that $f$ and $h$ have closed forms (and all the better if $f^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}_a$ do too), but that's not always possible.

Now let's apply this to the three-log case. We get
$$
\log_j(\log_j(\log_j x)) = \frac{1}{a}\ln\left[\frac{1}{a}\ln\left(\frac{y}{a} \right)\right] = \frac{\ln\ln(y/a)-\ln a}{a} = y\\\Longrightarrow \ln\ln(y/a)= ay + \ln a
$$
That double logarithm is going to make it very hard to find a way to isolate $a$ in closed form (or $y$, for that matter). Not saying its impossible, but it's pretty unlikely.

That said, we can get some info about $a(y)$ (and hence $j(x)$) from looking at [this plot by WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ContourPlot%5BLog%5By%2Fa%5D%3D%3Da*Exp%5Ba+y%5D%2C%7By%2C-1%2C3%7D%2C%7Ba%2C-3%2C1%7D%5D):

- The smallest value $x$ can take and have a solution is about $0.744$, with $j\approx 0.506$
- The largest value $j$ can take and have a solution is about $1.663$, with $x\approx5.27$.
- For $x$ values between the minimum value and $1$, there are two solutions. For $j$ values between the maximum value and $1$, there are also two solutions. There are no solutions with $j < 1 < x$ or $x < 1 < j$.
- $a(y)$ looks qualitatively like $W(y)$ for small $y$. However, for large $y$, $W(y)$ is unbounded, whereas it appears $a\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow \infty$

Anyone bold enough to try to find the exact value of those extremal points?